# Connect a facebook fan page with my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I had my own website and facebook fan page.I want to connect a facebook fan page with my site.
when ever i am posted any thing in my website it can autometically posted on my facebook fan page.please tell me how can i do that.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you post data use this

```
try {
          $post_id = $facebook->api("/".userid."/feed", "post",
          array(

          'message' => 'contents',
                              '
          )
          );
     } 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
     {
          error_log($e);
     }
```